# PHP - Adding a separator in a Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I asked this question yesterday but no one replied after I tried to get further help. I've been trying to figure out the problem in the code I was given in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828379/php-mysql-adding-a-row-in-the-middle-of-a-loop) but it's not giving me the results I want. Right now what it does is it writes a separator after each row but what I really want is if the name of the manager from the previous row is different then write a separator and keep going on with loop.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    $team = $row[0]['Manager'];
    foreach($row as $rows){
        if($rows['Manager'] !== $team){
            echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">Separator</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Manager']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Employee_ID']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing `$row` and `$rows`, you would be okay doing this:

```
$team = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    if($team && ($row['Manager'] != $team)){ // skip first separator
       echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">Separator</td></tr>";
    }
    $team = $row['Manager'];
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Manager']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Employee_ID']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: What's in `$row['Manager']` in each row?

Comment: It's the name of each manager. So basically the name of the manager repeats in each row if that employee ID and name is associated to them in the DB.

Comment: Try using `print_r($row)` and `print_r($team)` at the beginning of the loop to see what variable values are. There has to be something I can't test here, because this should work.

Comment: Nice! I love it! It worked. The problem was I put `$team = $row['Manager'];` inside `if` that's why it didn't work.

Comment: One more thing. The code works but let's say I want to put it at the bottom instead of the top the the loop since I want to use that row to sum the total. It would look weird if I sum the total at the top.

Comment: You put if condition and `$team = $row['Manager']` (note that assignment has to go **after** condition to the end of the loop. That's all :)

Comment: I tried that but after the first line, it echos the separator

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

    $team = $row[0]['Manager'];

    foreach($row as $rows){
        if($rows['Manager'] !== $team) {
            $team = $row['Manager'];
            echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">Separator</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Manager']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Employee_ID']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something, or can you simply display the data, then assign it to the variable further in the loop?

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    $team = $row[0]['Manager'];
    foreach($row as $rows){
    if($row['Manager'] !== $team){
        echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">".$team."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Manager']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Employee_ID']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $team = $row[0]['Manager'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code and it duplicated each line multiple times and added the separator on each row.

Answer (score 0):

What is `$rowS['Manager']` ? `$rowS` is unknown. use `$row['Manager']` like:

```
    if($row['Manager'] !== $team){
        echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">Separator</td></tr>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the value allocation `$team = $rows['Manager'];` in the if condition.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    $team = "";
    foreach($row as $rows){
        if($rows['Manager'] != $team){
            echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">Separator</td></tr>";
            $team = $rows['Manager'];
        }
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$rows['Manager']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$rows['Employee_ID']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$rows['Name']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```